# SQLCipher fails with I/O error for file size over 2GB on Android

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I am trying to encrypt a sqlite database that is over 2GB in size on Android. This causes the app to crash with an I/O error.
I am using the binaries for 3.1.0 available on the page at https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Is there a limit to the file size that can be used with the sqlCipher for Android.

Thanks.

[UPDATE]

The error I get is

```
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error
```

with the stack trace as

```
[net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method),
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:2092),
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1958),
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:875),
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:930),
com.puneet.android.sqlitesample.MainActivity.ConvertNormalToSQLCipheredDB(MainActivity.java:134),
com.puneet.android.sqlitesample.MainActivity.buttonEncryptionOnClick(MainActivity.java:69),
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method),
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515),
android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3978),
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654),
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438),
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733),
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95),
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146),
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602),
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method),
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515),
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283),
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099),
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)]
```

The file is 2GB in size.

Comment: "This causes the app to crash with an I/O error" -- please post the Java stack trace associated with the crash. "Is there a limit to the file size that can be used with the sqlCipher for Android" -- SQLite itself has a limit in the terabyte range. I am not aware that SQLCipher for Android imposes a lower limit, though it certainly is possible.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I have updated the question with the details. There is a discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlcipher/DoJzRVBUisQ that refers to file limits on sqlCipher